# Excel find data difference between two different columns in a table

Tags: arrays

I have an excel table, each table has a code and a result in different column , i want to know difference between results from different sheets by compare between results by the help of the code.the problem is that code is not in the same array or column it is in different column.please help me.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.